# default URL for a model in rails?

Tags: ruby-on-rails

I have a class Post

I want the default URL of each posts to be http://domain.com/9383 instead of http://domain.com/posts/9383

I tried to fix it in the routes. I manage to accept domain.com/222 but if I use <%= url_for(@posts) %> I still get domain.com/posts/222

How can I do it? Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can't change the behaviour of `url_for(@post)` with routes. `url_for` will assume a `map.resources` setup if an `ActiveRecord` instance is passed to it.

You should rather do this:

```
# routes.rb
map.post ":id", :controller => "posts", :action => "show"

# named route
post_path(@post)

# full link_to
link_to @post.title, post_path(@post)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you're using `url_for`, there's no way to tell it to omit the `/posts/` section. I think you would need to create helper, maybe in `application_helper.rb`

```
def post_url(post)
  "/#{post.id}"
end
```

Answer (score 0):

Overriding `url_for` seems to not be considered a best practice in Rails, although it seems terribly convenient to me.  Here's a description of how to do it by customizing `ApplicationController`: http://arjanvandergaag.nl/blog/generating-fancy-routes-with-rails.html